# Issue with a derivation in Marion's Dynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, calculus

I was solving problem 2-14 in Marion's "Classical dynamics of particles and systems" edition 5. In this problem we calculate the range of a trajectory to be $d=\frac{2{v_0}^2\cos{\alpha}\sin{(\alpha - \beta)}}{g\cos^2{\beta}}$ which is fine. But then the problem asks us to find the $\alpha$ that maximizes $d$. In the solution manual this is written: $$\frac{d}{d\alpha}(d)=0=\frac{2{v_0}^2}{g\cos^2\beta}[-\sin\alpha\sin(\alpha-\beta)+\cos\alpha\cos(\alpha-\beta)]\cos(2\alpha-\beta)$$and then it sets $\cos(2\alpha-\beta)$ equal to zero and finds $\alpha$. But I don't understand where $\cos(2\alpha-\beta)$ came from. It's not in the result of the derivation of $\cos\alpha\sin(\alpha - \beta)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's meant to be an equal sign in there: $$\frac{d}{d\alpha}(d)=0=\frac{2{v_0}^2}{g\cos^2\beta}[-\sin\alpha\sin(\alpha-\beta)+\cos\alpha\cos(\alpha-\beta)]\color{red}{=\cos(2\alpha-\beta)}$$ since $\cos\left(2\alpha - \beta\right) \equiv \cos(\alpha) \cos\left(\alpha-\beta\right)-\sin(\alpha) \sin\left(\alpha-\beta\right)$ is a trig identity, which allows you to simplify the messy expression above so you can solve for $\alpha$ explicitly.